# Android Parcelable class says: JavaBinder -> FAILED BINDER TRANSACTON.. (BIG-DATA)

Tags: java, android, decode, encode

Can parcalable class pass data over 40k?

My Parcalable class look like this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1450245/ (line: 228 and 261)

```
    public ApplicationsModel(Parcel parcal)
    {
        this();
        this.setId(parcal.readLong());
        this.setName(parcal.readString());
        this.setKeywords(parcal.readString());
        this.setPrice(parcal.readString());
        this.setVersion(parcal.readString());
        this.setScreenshot_url(parcal.readString());

        this.setSupport_url(parcal.readString());
        this.setLicense(parcal.readString());
        this.setWebsite(parcal.readString());
        this.setArchive_root(parcal.readString());

        // end in error
        this.setDescription(parcal.readString());
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ApplicationsModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ApplicationsModel>() 
    {
        @Override
        public ApplicationsModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ApplicationsModel(source);
        }
        @Override
        public ApplicationsModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ApplicationsModel[size];
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(getId());
        dest.writeString(getName());
        dest.writeString(getKeywords());
        dest.writeString(getPrice());
        dest.writeString(getVersion());
        dest.writeString(getScreenshot_url());

        dest.writeString(getSupport_url());
        dest.writeString(getLicense());
        dest.writeString(getWebsite());
        dest.writeString(getArchive_root());

        // end in error
        dest.writeString(getDescription());
    }
```

It works with data like Id, Keywords...

But If i try with 'Description' it end up in:

> JavaBinder !! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTON !!

**The *'Description'* data like this:**

```
Visually create your websites by using drag & drop (WYSIWYG).\nQuick 'n Easy Web Builder is not an HTML editor, but an HTML generator! You can visually (WYSIWYG) create your websites by using drag & drop. Place objects (Text, Lines, Images, Shapes, Slideshows, Galleries, Forms etc) anywhere on the page (pixel perfect layouts). \r\nNow you can create amazing websites without having to learn HTML!\r\n\r\n- Desktop Publishing for the Web! Create websites as easy as drag and drop.\r\n- Outputs HTML4, XHTML, PHP or HTML5\r\n- Built-in support for CSS3 opacity, box-shadow, border-radius, gradients.\r\n- Site Management. Easily add, edit, clone and structure your web pages from a single file.\r\n- Easily create forms using the built-in Form Wizard or manually with a large selection of form tools\r\n- Built-in PHP form processor (send email, upload file to a folder on the server).\r\n- Built-in form validation (message box, info bubble or HTML5)\r\n- Advanced graphics tools like shapes, rotation, shadows, reflection and more than 50 other image effects.\r\n- Style manager for global styling (CSS)\r\n- Gradient Manager, create awesome multi-color gradient effects!\r\n- Publish to local drive or a FTP server using the build-in FTP manager.\r\n- Built-in Slide Shows, Photo Galleries, Rollover images, Logos etc.\r\n- Sitemap generator.\r\n- Supports JavaScript events with (optional) jQuery animations!\r\n- PayPal eCommerce Tools. \r\n- Many navigation tools available: Navigation bars, tab menus, dropdown menus, slidemenus.\r\n- More than 50 ready-to-use JavaScripts (galleries, text effects, social media etc.)\r\n- Template support. Already more than 100 templates available!\r\n- Support for YouTube, Flash Video, HTML5 Video/Audio and many other video formats.\r\n- Add external scripts and other code with the HTML object.\r\n- and much more!\r\n"
```

So do I need to save the 'Description'-data into a local-file or is there a better/faster way to do this?